# Facing issue with routing router name property in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-router

I have an angular 5 app having 3 modules. The structure of three modules is as described:
I have a parent module appModule and there are two module child to appModule. Let me call them modulex and moduley.

I have a routing file in appmodule to route to modulex and moduley routing file.

But now I want to have another routing module in modulex. So it only changes the content on the part of the page.

I know its bit difficult to understand please ask questions for more clarity. Below is my code:

appmodule.routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: 'modulex', loadChildren: 'app/modules/modulex.module#modulex'},
   { path: 'moduley', loadChildren: 'app/modules/moduley.module#moduley' }
];
```

And my app.component.html file:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

modulex.routing file:

```
    const modulexRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: ModulexComponent},
    {path: 'test', component: testComponent, 
        children:[ 
            {path: '', component: testDetailComponent,outlet: 'dashboard'} 
        ] 
    }
];
```

modulex.component.html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <app-header></app-header>
  <div class="container">
      <router-outlet name="dashboard"></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

My requirement is if i visit modulex/test it should render in `<router-outlet name="dashboard"></router-outlet>`.  But as on now it is rendering in app.component.html router outlet.

Please let me know any possible solution to it.

Comment: Which component's template is your `modulex.component.html`? Is it `testComponent`'s? The filename doesn't seem to match your class names.

Comment: @DarthJDG Updated code. I am sorry for all this confusion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your `ModuleXComponent` in the `modulex.routing` file and specify all sub-routes as children:

```
const modulexRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: ModuleXComponent, children: [
            { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: sampleComponent },
            { path: 'test', component: testComponent, outlet: 'dashboard' }
        ]
    }
];
```

This makes sure that `ModuleXComponent` is rendered first for all routes under `/modulex`.

The route `/modulex` will render `sampleComponent` within `ModuleXComponent`'s `router-outlet` (`pathMatch: 'full'` makes sure it only matches the root of `/modulex`).

Similarly, `/modulex/test` will render `testComponent` within `ModuleXComponent`'s `router-outlet`.

Comment: Yes, I tried like this way also but then my page is getting blank and no errors on console.

Comment: @TavishAggarwal What is `sampleComponent`? You didn't mention it in your question. Do you want to display it as I described? (only when your route is `/modulex`)

Comment: I have updated the question. Please refer it and let me know if you have any questions. I want to access route modulex/test